# What does it mean in Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory for differentiable functions $E,F,G, l,m,n$ to sastify the Codazzi and Gauss equations?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is the full statement of Fundamental Theorem of Surface Theory:

"Existence: Given differentiable functions $E, F, G, l, m$, and $n$ with $E > 0$ and $EG  - F^2 > 0$ and satisfying the Codazzi and Gauss equations, there exists (locally) a parametrized surface $x(u, v)$ with the respective I and II."

This is from Shifrin Differential Geometry.

I'm trying to solve a problem where given $E, F, G, l, m, n$ which are the fundamental forms. Can you tell whether there is a parametrized surface.

For example $E = G = 1, F = 0, l = 1 = -n, m = 0$;

$E > 0$ and $EG-F^2 = 1 > 0$, but how do I use the second fundamental form $l, m$ and $n$?

Comment: Customary to use symbols of  second fundamental form coefficients $ L,M,N$ or $e,f,g$

Comment: @Narasimham: That's *your* custom, perhaps, but far from globally accepted.

Comment: Have you tried testing the Codazzi and Gauss equations?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin okay.. earlier $(l,m,n)$  also used to denote 3D vector direction ratios/coefficients..

Comment: You're starting with functions $E,F,G,\ell,m,n$ which are completely anonymous except for satisfying $E>0$, $EG-F^2>0$, and a certain system of partial differential equations (Gauss and Codazzi). *Then*, there is a surface whose geometry is given by these functions. Are these constant functions you're starting with a solution to the partial differential equations?

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand the curvature is
$$K=\dfrac{ln−m^2}{EG−F^2}=-1$$
while with the metric $E=G=1,F=0$ the Chrsitroffel symbols are zero, that is, $K=0$.